# Auto-update feature for wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, auto-update, gitversion

I am trying to do auto-update process. I having my updated version exe in my GitHub When I start the lower version exe from my local machine. It really want me ask me for update. That updated should be check from the GitHub updated exe. Consider my file size in GitHub will be 4GB. And I don't know whether the GitHub exe file updated or not. But, I need to download that into my local machine. and I am checking the version. If the both local and GitHub version's same means. here my running time will waste. Thats why i am checking the version before download.

Please consider this scenario and provide a better solution. How i can achieve this auto-update.

Comment: Have a look into ClickOnce. This might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a windows service for checking the current version in the server(Maybe you can store these value in a xml) & then this service can download the latest update